# Is there way to create trigger for get ref value when insert data?

Tags: sql, oracle

I create table using types in oracle. I have data file in csv. I need to get ref value for patient table when inserting data.

```
CREATE TYPE Location_t as OBJECT(
L_id varchar(6),
lon NUMBER(9,6),
lat NUMBER(9,6),
country varchar(26),
Province varchar(26)
)
/

create type patient_t as object(
p_id  varchar(10),
ReportedDate date,
Deadts int,
recover int,
confirmed int,
loc ref location_t
)

create table Location of location_t
(L_id PRIMARY KEY)
/

CREATE TABLE PATIENT of patient_t
(p_id PRIMARY KEY,
loc references  Location)
```

Location table data is already inserted and i need to get ref code for patient.

location table

[image]

patient table

[image]

Comment: Have you considered writing PL/SQL code to read the CSV file and insert the data rather than relying on SQL Developer's import wizard? Maybe use external tables and MERGE statement?

Comment: is there any way to create trigger using sqlplus?

Comment: why need of trigger here?   You are selecting Location on based of input, which can be done by joins

Comment: please, can you tell me how to do it .

Comment: [edit] your question and post sample data from your CSV file.